# Where can I get a dataset of ultrasound images?

Tags: data-request

I have a machine learning task that i wish to pursue - disease detection by ultrasound image analysis. For the task i will need labeled(diseased or healthy) ultrasound images dataset. Please suggest how and where can i get it.

Comment: if you don't find something published, then I'd get in touch with the authors of the many recent academic papers.